# Creating a facebook scraper

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I tried to make a facebook bot to parse the profile links. However, it signs in and parses the content of left-sided bar inconsistently. I can't go further. Could anyone point me in the right direction so that i can rectify my mistakes I've made already in my code and parse the profile links. Here is the code:

```
strdata = "email=sth.com&pass=xxx"
http.Open "POST", "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send strdata

html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("_li")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each topic In topics
    Cells(x, 1) = topic.innerText
    x = x + 1
Next topic
```

Comment: You should read this first: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php?hc_location=ufi

Comment: Yep, I finished reading it just now. I don't have any dishonest will  to use the collected data otherwise. It is solely for my learning purpose. Hope you understand what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanWildry Sometimes I wonder how other companies get away with it ... or maybe they don't really care?

Comment: They probably want you to use their API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: Thanks sir for the link and your invaluable suggestions. Btw, could you please give me a link or something following which i can learn how to use API in VBA cause I have never worked with API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content of facebook, either one has to deal with api or to use selenium which is definitely the worst way. However, my below script can log in to the page and parse some titles:

```
Sub Grabbing_item()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With driver
        .get "https://www.facebook.com/"
        .FindElementById("email").SendKeys ("email_id")
        .FindElementById("pass").SendKeys ("Pass_word")
        .FindElementById("u_0_2").Click
        .Wait 5
        html.body.innerHTML = .ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;")
        .Quit
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("profileLink")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ruguy72, that was very close to the solution. If you give a little push on column D where innertext is getting scraped, I think it might work. I just wanted to have profile names of different users visible in my homepage. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the exact link?  Post the exact URL. The idea of getting data in ColA, B, and C, is to do something like: If itm.tagname = "your_search" Then . . . or  If itm.classname = "your_search" Then . . . So, if there is a match, grab itm.innertext.  You should be able to find a pattern and exploit it to do what you need.  Although, as it was mentioned above, if you can get the API working, that's probably the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: If it helped you, please mark my answer as helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Dear bro, I marked your answer helpful. It is someone else who pressed the downvote button that's why it seems to you that it is me. Thanks.